# Validating Checkbox States With jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery form validator plugin. The form has 5 check boxes. The first of which (master), if checked, checks the remaining 4 and makes them unalterable by the user. If master is unchecked, the remaining 4 boxes go back to being togglable by the user.  This functionality works fine. Now, what I want to do is, if all of the check boxes are **unchecked**, invalidate the form. I also want one specific area (checkBoxErrorHolder) to house the validation error message for the check boxes only. The other error messages should appear in their default positions by their inputs. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("validateCheckBoxes",
                          function (value, element, params)   {

                              var master=false, 
                                  slave1=false, 
                                  slave2=false,
                                  slave3=false,
                                  slave4=false;

                              if ($("#master").attr("checked"))
                                  master = true;
                              if ($("#slave1").attr("checked"))
                                  slave1 = true;
                              if ($("#slave2").attr("checked"))
                                  slave2 = true;
                              if ($("#slave3").attr("checked"))
                                  slave3 = true;
                              if ($("#slave4").attr("checked"))
                                  slave4 = true;

                              return (master || (slave1&&slave2&&slave3&&slave4));
                          }, 
                          "One or more check boxes must be checked");

    $("#theForm").validate({
        rules: { 
                   first: required,
                   last:  required,
                   email: {required: true, email: true},
                   master: { required: true, 
                             validateCheckBoxes: true},
                             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                                 $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error);
                                             }
                           }
                   slave1: { required: true, 
                             validateCheckBoxes: true},
                             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                                 $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error);
                                             }
                           }
                   slave2: { required: true,
                             validateCheckBoxes: true},
                             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                                 $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error);
                                             }
                           }
                   slave3: { required: true, 
                             validateCheckBoxes: true},
                             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                                 $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error);
                                             }
                           }
                   slave4: { required: true, 
                             validateCheckBoxes: true,
                             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                                 $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error);
                                             }
                           }
               },
        messages: {
            first: "required",
            last: "required",
            email: {
                       required: "Email address required",
                       email: "Please supply a valid email address"
                   }
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form id="theForm" ...>
<input type="text" name="first" value="" />
<input type="text" name="last" value="" />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" id="master" value="master" class="validateCheckBoxes"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="slave1" value="slave1" class="validateCheckBoxes"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="slave2" value="slave2" class="validateCheckBoxes"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="slave3" value="slave3" class="validateCheckBoxes"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="slave4" value="slave4" class="validateCheckBoxes"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="checkBoxErrorHolder"></div>
```

Needless to say, I'm not getting the results I expected.

Comment: all your `.attr("checked)` are missing their closing quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
rules: { 
               first: required,
               last:  required,
               email: {required: true, email: true},
               master: { required: true, 
                         validateCheckBoxes: true},
                         errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                             $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error);
                                         }
                       } // <-- missing comma
               slave1: { required: true, 
                         validateCheckBoxes: true},
                         errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                             $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error);
                                         }
                       } // <-- missing comma
```

**Basically, you broke the plugin through a variety of syntax and formatting errors...**

---

**1)** `errorPlacement` is **not a rule** that you apply along with the other rules.  [It's a *callback function* that you apply *once* along with the other options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#theForm").validate({
        rules: {
            // your rules
        },
        messages: {
            // your messages
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $("#checkBoxErrorHolder ").html(error);
        },
        // other options and callback functions,
    });

});
```

---

**2)**  Your `checkbox` elements are missing a `name` attribute.  Every input, select, radio, checkbox, etc., except for the submit button, **must** have a `name` attribute in order for this plugin to function properly.

---

**3)**  Whenever you use the shorthand for a rule like `required`, it must be in quotes.  Here's an example showing both ways correctly...

```
rules: {
    first: "required",
    last: {
        required: true
    },
},
```

---

**4)**  I started constructing a jsFiddle for this <s>but I stopped because there are way too many syntax errors than I care to fix</s>.  <s>Please run your JavaScript through jsFiddle's jsHint function to see them all.</s>  I got your basic validation working <s>so now you can troubleshoot your custom `validateCheckBoxes` method</s>.

Here's a working jsFiddle Demo of your basic form:  **http://jsfiddle.net/gHKyb/**

---

**5) EDIT:**  I took another look at your custom `validateCheckBoxes` method and cleaned up the last of the syntax errors.  But it still wasn't working because you accidentally defined a `required` rule on every checkbox, which simply means that the checkbox *is always required despite anything else*.

I removed the `required` rule from all checkboxes and everything seems to work now as per your spec.  I also condensed your code.  (either the first box must be checked OR the last four must be checked)

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateCheckBoxes", function (value, element, params) {
    var master,
        slave = [];
    if ($("#master").attr("checked")) {
        master = true;
    }
    $("[id^='slave']").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            slave[i+1] = true;
        }
    });
    return (master || (slave[1] && slave[2] && slave[3] && slave[4]));
}, "One or more check boxes must be checked");
```

---

**6)** And finally, to fix the placement of your error labels, I simply modified the `errorPlacement` callback function as follows:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if ($(element).attr("type") === "checkbox") {
        $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html(error); // just for checkboxes
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element); // default placement
    }
},
success: function() { // need "success" to dynamically clear any checkbox errors
    $("#checkBoxErrorHolder").html();
},
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/AKgmH/**

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply @Sparky. A lot of the code errors you found were due to typos in transcribing. The code is on a different network than that of the machine that's attached to the Internet. My main error was #6: multiple errorPlacement's. I cleaned that up and it works for the most part. I also changed the return value to:
    return (master || (slave[1] || slave[2] || slave[3] || slave[4]));

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a " is missing after each 'checked'

```
if ($("#master").attr("checked"))
  master = true;
if ($("#slave1").attr("checked"))
  slave1 = true;
if ($("#slave2").attr("checked"))
  slave2 = true;
if ($("#slave3").attr("checked"))
  slave3 = true;
if ($("#slave4").attr("checked"))
  slave4 = true;
```

I don't know if it will resolve your problem, but it can help :)

Comment: That's just the tip of the iceberg.